# Can I use a different SVN tool on same repo?

Tags: svn

I just migrated from Windows to Mac OS X and have found theres no version of Tortoise SVN for Mac... Is it ok to use another tool such as [svnX](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx/features/) to interact with the same repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that will be fine. They're all just GUIs for SVN anyway, behind the scenes they do the same things.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other "better" SVN tools for Mac?

Comment: @htmlr I'm not sure as I don't use a Mac. Maybe the SCPlugin which supposedly integrates well with Finder: http://scplugin.tigris.org/

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN actually uses [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) as its backend.
svnX will just do the same.

So yes, you can use both on the same repo.

Comment: Thanks heaps, but accepting ascii limes response as he/she was first